# Is it possible to draw a limited lines in Corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have tried to draw a line by using corona sdk. Is there any way to draw a limited numbers of lines during the run time...?

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/draw-line

```
display.newLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY)
```

Comment: Tanq Secator.But This was only draw a line, I want to  sketch a line during the runtime if it is possible ...?

Comment: You wanted to draw a line. That's the code which draws a line. If you need something else please update the question.

Comment: I was tried to swiping mouse over simulator to produce random colored lines. I did that, by using this link developer.coronalabs.com/code/draw-line.. Here whenever I swipe simulator a new line was draw but I want only a few line when I swipe mouse over simulator.Is it possible....?